# eclipse running programs without jdk

Tags: java, eclipse

Why is it that we do not need a jdk installation to compile and execute java programs in eclipse. a jre installation suffice. but while running the code from cmd we need to have jdk installed. 
does eclipse comes with any alternate javac. I tried searching for javac in eclipse folder, but did not got any result. please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has its own compiler so it can compile java programs. It doesn't look at your path variable to find javac.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse has its own builtin incremental compiler. To run your projects it requires a JRE, you can go to `Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> libraries` and see a default JRE library added to your project (You can modify this if you want your program running on other java versions or for example IBM JDK).

A JRE is required on your system to run eclipse itself, which is metioned either in the path variable or specified in `eclipse.ini` file (Eclipse also uses this JRE version and automatically set the default project compile compliance level at this level).

The parameter to include in eclipse.ini to run eclipse, before -vmargs, is..

-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

Running a java program does not require a JDK, developing and compiling does. If you just want to run a Java program all you need is a Java Runtime Engine (JRE). As Eclipse is an Integrated Development Environment(IDE) that eases the development process for you, and for many other reasons it is bundled with its own compiler.